# Как добавить видео на сайт

Tags: php, html, видео, youtube

Добрый день. Появилась такая проблема - есть страница на которой должны быть уменьшенные превью к видео и есть страница где это видео должно быть большого размера.
Пользователь добавляет видео с помощью HTML-кода:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E9993V1ocHM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Запись добавляется в бд и потом выводится на страницах.
Моя проблема состоит в следующем - как сделать что бы на странице с маленькими превью они были маленькими, вот такого плана http://joxi.ru/MAjJekbiB4Z8Ae . Получается что у меня одна запись выводится на двух разных страницах, но на одной из них нужно что бы видео было маленьким. 
Сейчас у меня на страницах такой код:

```
<iframe width="200" height="100" src="<?= $item1->video ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

В `<?= $item1->video ?>` вставляется ссылка такого вида:   `https://www.youtube.com/embed/E9993V1ocHM`, а такие ссылки:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9993V1ocHM`, `https://youtu.be/E9993V1ocHM` не работают.
Можно как то выводить видео по двум последним ссылкам? Или же нужно добавлять `<iframe...` и написать парсер, который будет брать нужную часть из бд и вставлять ее на страницу ? Надеюсь понятно рассказал. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте инструмент **[YouTube Thumbnail Grabber](https://boingboing.net/features/getthumbs.html)** для выделения/определения миниатюры выбранного видео. Я назвал эту миниатюру: hqdefault.jpg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E9993V1ocHM"><img src="hqdefault.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Вы не поняли. Мне не нужна миниатюра в виде картинки. Мне нужно что бы по одной ссылке отображалось два видео - одно 200х100, а второе 560х315.